# Browser with single connection

Tags: browser, httpserver

I'm trying to serve a single-page-application by serving HTTP from a very limited hardware with a single socket available (all other sockets are already serving other protocols).

All served files are working, as long I request them individually.

But, when opening the `index.html` in Chrome it immediately tries to read the linked files (.js, .css, some images, etc), and, since my server has only one socket, and it is still being used by  `index.html`, my server refuses the connection. Chrome gives up without any new try.

There is any way I can force Chrome (and other browsers), to use a single connection? I mean, to force it to close the current connection and open again for the next asset, or even send a new request on the same connection (without closing it), after the current asset completes.

My HTTP server identify itself with version 1.1, already tried header `Connection` both with `close` and `keep-alive` and got the same issue.

Any magical header to solve this issue? HTTP 1 or 2 maybe?

Comment: "all other sockets are already serving other protocols", I'm confused, do you mean all other *ports* are taken? But that shouldn't be a problem since a single port can serve multiple incoming connections. And even if you tell the browser to use a single connection, nothing stops others to connect to your server at the same time.

Comment: It's a small hardware using an external TCP/UDP interface to the ethernet (W5500). It has 8 sockets, period! We have 6 of them doing the "official" product tasks. And we thought it was a good idea to use one of the 2 spares to serve HTTP and use it as an eventual configuration access. We don't care about speed or simultaneous access to this port. I guess I can solve my issue by creating a single HTML with all JS and CSS inline. Should work but sill looking for a nicer way to solve it.